# how to get auto changing background image after few seconds?

Tags: android, background-image

i'm working on an Android application in which i want the background image to be changed after every 5 seconds. i have all the images in my drawable folder.

i am giving the code which i am using but i am not getting the output. As an output i am getting a still image which is not changing.

Please help

Thanks

[CODE]

```
public class Home extends Activity {

public static int count=0;
int[] drawablearray=new int[]{R.drawable.slider_1,R.drawable.slider_2,R.drawable.slider_3,R.drawable.slider_4,R.drawable.slider_5};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

           if(count<drawablearray.length){

               Home.this.getWindow().
                   setBackgroundDrawableResource(drawablearray[count]);
               count++;  //<<< increment counter here
            }
           else{
              // reset counter here
              count=0;
            }

          }
      }, 5000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Timer

```
public class Home extends Activity {

public static int count=0;
int[] drawablearray=new int[]{R.drawable.slider_1,R.drawable.slider_2,R.drawable.slider_3,R.drawable.slider_4,R.drawable.slider_5};
Timer _t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    lnMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnMain);
        _t = new Timer();
        _t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // run on ui thread
                {
                    public void run() {
                        if (count < drawablearray.length) {

                            lnMain.setBackgroundDrawable(drawablearray[count]);
                            count = (count + 1) % drawablearray.length;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 5000, 5000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {    
       Home.this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(drawablearray[count]);
       count += (count+1)%drawablearray.length;  //<<< increment counter here
       h.postDelayed(this, 5000);    
    }
 };
```

now call like

```
h.postDelayed(r, 5000);
```

Comment: made two minor changes please check now

Comment: if i directly put this code in onCreate, i cant use the function h.postDelayed inside the body. If i define Handler and Runnable before onCreate then i dont get any picture as background.

Comment: its saying value of r is never used

Comment: and even then its not producing any image on the background

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have a look at the ViewFlipper class
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Comment: please give some example of it as I am new to android app development

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be easier to work with the xmls. You can change the background of the main layout of the activity.

Try something like this:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

public static int count=0;
int[] drawablearray=new int[]{R.drawable.slider_1,R.drawable.slider_2,R.drawable.slider_3,R.drawable.slider_4,R.drawable.slider_5};

LinearLayout ll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewByID(R.id.mainlayout) //It depends of the name that you gave to it

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
               ll.setBackgroundDrawable(drawablearray[count]);
               // or ll.setBackgroundResource(resid) if you want.
               count += (count+1)%drawablearray.length;
          }
      }, 5000);
}
}
```

Comment: Sir i have tried to use this code but still i'm getting just one picture in background